# Subscribe only to tail property in a chain of properties

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a view model which has a property A. Property A is of a type which has a property B. Now I want to subscribe in my view model's constructor to any direct change of property B. By "direct" I mean that I want to run my subscription only if property B of the current value of property A is changing but not if the value of property A is changed.

By now I have something like this:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.A.B)
    .Subscribe(b => DoSomethingWithB(b));
```

However, this will of course also execute `DoSomethingWithB` if the value of property A changes. I have already tried around whether `WhenAnyObservable` or `Switch` extension methods can be used but up to now I couldn't figure out what it has to look like.

Edit:

Since I don't know whether my initial question was clear enough I have added now a working example covering all cases that I need to take into account. For simplicity, property B is of type `int` and I have added an ID property to `TypeA` to be able to distinguish them.

```
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ObservePropertyTail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

            // Pings but should not because A was changed.
            vm.A = new TypeA(1) { B = 1 };

            // Pings which is the desired behavior.
            vm.A.B = 2;

            // Does not ping (by chance because value of B remains the
            // same although A is changed) which is the desired behavior.
            vm.A = new TypeA(2) { B = 2 };

            // Pings but should not because A was changed.
            vm.A = new TypeA(3) { B = 3 };

            // Should not ping and does not.
            vm.A = null;

            // Should not ping but does.
            vm.A = new TypeA(4) { B = 4 };

            // Should ping and does.
            vm.A.B = 3;
        }
    }

    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private TypeA a;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.A.B)
                .Subscribe(b => Console.WriteLine($"Ping: A = {A.ID}, b = {b}"));
        }

        public TypeA A
        {
            get => a;
            set
            {
                if (a != value)
                {
                    a = value;
                    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(A)));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    class TypeA : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int b;

        public TypeA(int id) => ID = id;

        public int ID { get; }

        public int B
        {
            get => b;
            set
            {
                if (b != value)
                {
                    b = value;
                    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(B)));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ping: A = 1, b = 1
Ping: A = 1, b = 2
Ping: A = 3, b = 3
Ping: A = 4, b = 4
Ping: A = 4, b = 3
```

Comment: Is it an option to use `DistinctUntilChanged()`?

Comment: "However, this will of course also execute DoSomethingWithB if the value of property A changes" - No, it shouldn't.

Comment: I have now added a working example to my question to demonstrate that it does not behave as intended, resp. to make clear what the desired behavior is.

Comment: In your *working* example. Why shouldn't in the first case no ping be made? B changed from 0 to 1. The second pings also, because it changed from 1 to 2. The third doesn't ping, cause it didn't change B (is still 2) and in the last case you changed both A and B (B got from 2 to 3). So IMHO it works as expected. Whenever B changes (regardless of A) your subscription is being called.

Comment: Hm, seems that I am still misunderstood: I know that the behavior of my demo application is as intended by the developers of Reactive Extensions and ReactiveUI, so it's not that I think that I have discovered a bug. My actual question is whether there is a filter operator or a different approach to achieve the behavior that is described in my demo code. `DistinceUntilChanged` goes in the right direction and I tried to use the overload that accepts a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer` but without succes.

Comment: Some context to make clear what this is about in my real application: Users can set the current value of `A` by picking instances of `TypeA` from a list. The properties of  `A` will then be shown in an editor so that the user can change them which will subsequently trigger expensive updates. What I want to achieve is that further updates are only triggered when the user modifies the properties of the current instance of `TypeA` but not if the current instance of `TypeA` is switched.

Comment: @Đøharrrck In your last example, you don't want to receive a ping because the `A` property has been changed. But what about the value of `B`? It has been "changed" from `2` to `3`. Do you still not want to receive a ping for this pseudo-"change" of `B`?

Comment: @Progman No, I only want to receive a ping in the case that property `B` of the current object `A` was changed but NOT in the case that `B` has changed only because the current instance of `A` was replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ObservableForProperty()` to build an `IObservable<T>` for the properties you have, which will not fire the initial value they have. This in combination with `Switch()` allows you to build an `IObservable<T>` for the property `B`, which will only fire changes to the property `B`, but not when the property `A` is changed. The code might look like this:

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
vm.ObservableForProperty(it => it.A)
    .Select(it => it.Value)
    .Select(it => it.ObservableForProperty(it2 => it2.B))
    .Switch()
    .Select(it => it.Value)
    .Subscribe(it => {
        Console.WriteLine("B is: "+it);
    });
    
// Pings but should not because A was changed.
vm.A = new TypeA(1) { B = 1 };

// Pings which is the desired behavior.
vm.A.B = 2;

// Does not ping (by chance because value of B remains the
// same although A is changed) which is the desired behavior.
vm.A = new TypeA(2) { B = 2 };

// Pings but should not because A was changed.
vm.A = new TypeA(3) { B = 3 };

// Should not ping and does not.
vm.A = null;

// Should not ping but does.
vm.A = new TypeA(4) { B = 4 };

// Should ping and does.
vm.A.B = 3;
```

This will generate the following output:

```
B is: 2
B is: 3
```

As you see, it will only trigger when the property `B` is changed, but will not trigger when `A` is changed. Also, you have *one* observable on the property `B` and will not notice that the inner value for `A` is changed due to the `Switch()` call.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I had expected that the `switch` method could somehow be used for for this but could not figure out how. Btw: I have come up with my own solution in the meantime but it looks much like overdoing. I will post it in a second answer.

Comment: One addition: I have added a `Where` after the first `Select` to filter out those cases where `A` is set to to `null`. This case was not part of my original demo code but can happen in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer @Progman's answer and have accepted it as correct, I would like to post my own solution of the problem. It is based on `WhenAnyDynamic` but puts a subject into the observer pipeline that intercepts notifications and compares the current value of the tail property's parent object with the previous instance. It then only forwards those notification where the tail's parent has not changed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace Bruker.Spr.Analyzer.ViewModels.PreProcessing.ReportPoints
{
    public static class WhenAnyCustomExtensions
    {
        public static IObservable<TRet> WhenAnyTailValue<TSender, TRet>(
            this TSender sender,
            Expression<Func<TSender, TRet>> expression)
        {
            var tailObserver = new TailObservable<TSender, TRet>(sender, expression);

            return tailObserver;
        }

        private class TailObservable<TSender, TRet> : ISubject<TRet>
        {
            private readonly TSender sender;
            private readonly Func<TSender, object> tailParentFunc;
            private readonly List<IObserver<TRet>> observers = new List<IObserver<TRet>>();

            private object previousTailParent;

            public TailObservable(TSender sender, Expression<Func<TSender, TRet>> expression)
            {
                this.sender = sender;

                var chainElementsWithoutTail = expression.Body
                    .GetExpressionChain()
                    .SkipLast(1);

                if (chainElementsWithoutTail.Any())
                {
                    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSender), "x");

                    Expression tailMemberExpression = parameterExpression;

                    foreach (var property in chainElementsWithoutTail.OfType<MemberExpression>())
                    {
                        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(tailMemberExpression, property.Member.Name);
                        tailMemberExpression = member;
                    }

                    var trimmedUnaryExpression = Expression.Convert(tailMemberExpression, typeof(object));
                    var trimmedLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSender, object>>(trimmedUnaryExpression, new[] { parameterExpression });

                    this.tailParentFunc = trimmedLambdaExpression.Compile();
                }

                sender
                    .WhenAnyDynamic(expression.Body, x => (TRet)x.Value)
                    .Subscribe(this);
            }

            public void OnCompleted()
            {
                foreach (var observer in this.observers)
                {
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
            }

            public void OnError(Exception error)
            {
                foreach (var observer in this.observers)
                {
                    observer.OnError(error);
                }
            }

            public void OnNext(TRet value)
            {
                if (this.tailParentFunc == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var currentTailParent = this.tailParentFunc(this.sender);

                try
                {
                    if (currentTailParent != this.previousTailParent)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    foreach (var observer in this.observers)
                    {
                        observer.OnNext(value);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.previousTailParent = currentTailParent;
                }
            }

            public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TRet> observer)
            {
                if (!this.observers.Contains(observer))
                {
                    this.observers.Add(observer);
                }

                return new TailObserverSubscription<TRet>(this.observers, observer);
            }

            private sealed class TailObserverSubscription<TValue> : IDisposable
            {
                private readonly List<IObserver<TValue>> observers;
                private readonly IObserver<TValue> observer;

                public TailObserverSubscription(List<IObserver<TValue>> observers, IObserver<TValue> observer)
                {
                    this.observers = observers;
                    this.observer = observer;
                }

                public void Dispose()
                {
                    if (this.observer != null && this.observers.Contains(this.observer))
                    {
                        this.observers.Remove(this.observer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```